# Fullcalendar: add HTML tag next to the "titleformat"

Tags: jquery, html, fullcalendar

I use the jQuery Fullcalendar agenda component. My goal is to associate an action with each date displayed in the calendar, and to allow the opening of a separate window on each date.

So I need to add a button or a link next to the date(s) formatted via "**titleFormat**" in the first line of the agenda:

I see how to change the date format, but not how to insert another HTML element..

---

Meantime, I found an example that is close to what I want to do, but if the code fragment seems simple to me, I don't see how to incorporate it into the component settings ... 
And unfortunately, its documentation http://fullcalendar.io/docs/display/dayRender/ still seems to me obscure.

```
eventRender: function (event, element) {
  var dataToFind = moment(event.start).format('YYYY-MM-DD');
  $("td[data-date='"+dataToFind+"']").addClass('activeDay');
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The day render function allows you to modify the cell in any you want. If we get it as a JQuery object, we can add any element we wish:

```
  dayRender:function(date, cell){
    $(cell).html('<span>' + date + '</span>');
  }
```

An example Fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/Lty1z0sm/2/

**Update**
I believe what you were looking for was the viewRender callback:

```
viewRender:function(view, element){
  var date = moment(view.start).format('YYYY-MM-DD');
  element.find('.fc-day-header').append('<button data-date="' + date + '" type="button">My Button</button>');
}
```

Here is a working Fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/Lty1z0sm/3/

Comment: Thank you @MasNotsram for your answer. But, with your example, I realize  that I made a mistake in speaking of dayRender (): the part of the calendar that I would change is that where this is the name of the day, at its top  ( class "fc-day-header fc-widget-header" )

Comment: @Didier68 Ah I see! Do you have a link to a JSFiddle and/or website with your current code? That would give a clearer picture of what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: @Didier68 Scratch that, I've updated my answer. I think it solves your issue.

Comment: thank you very much for your help, that is exactly what I wanted as a solution! I wish you well celebrate the transition to 2016.

Comment: @Didier68 Glad I could help, you too! Happy New Year!